# Trying to concatenate very large video files with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have about anywhere from 10-24 mp4 files that are about 1 hour in length each and when I try to concatenate them into one I am only left with a 1 hour output.mp4 where its only content is of that of the first 1 hour video I fed in with the audio completely choppy.

Has anyone tried to run ffmpeg to form a very large video file?

This is one of the ffmpeg commands I ran

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i videos.txt -an -filter:v "setpts=0.01*PTS"  total_output.mkv
```

Comment: All input videos must have the same properties in order for concat to work.

Comment: So that’s the thing, my camera records 15min segment videos for each hour. I can combine those perfectly fine and pretty quick. So when I have those hourly videos in the same folder and try to concatenate again to form one 24 hour video, ffmpeg starts complaining. Any idea? I can show you what the log is like when I’m home

Comment: Log will be required.